# The shell's "delete word" shortcut deletes too many characters

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, line-editor

Under Bash some behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> has been driving me crazy since years and I figured out that maybe it could be fixed with a setting.

If I'm at a terminal and issue a command like this:

```
...$   cat >> ~/notesSuperLongFilename.txt
```

and then if I want, say, to issue :

```
...$ scp ~/notesSuperLongFilename.txt
```

I'd like to get back the "cat >> ~/notesSuperLongFilename.txt" using Ctrl+p (previous line) and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> again so I'd have:

```
...$  ~/notesSuperLongFilename.txt
```

and then I'd be able to simply enter "scp" and then do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (or hit Enter / Return).

However it doesn't work because after the first <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> I get:

```
...$ >> ~/notesSuperLongFilename.txt
```

(so far so good)

but after the second <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> I get:

```
...$ .txt
```

So for some reason <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> deletes *">> ~/notesSuperLongFilename"* at once instead of just deleting *">> "*.

This has to be the single biggest time-waster that is driving me crazy with Linux / Bash since literally years.

So how can I fix this (arguably broken) behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>?

P.S: I don't know who's "responsible" for that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> behavior: I don't know if it's the terminal or if it's the shell (Bash in my case).

Comment: after "cat >> ~/notesSuperLongFilename.txt", type "scp " and then Esc,. (Escape one time and then the "." character one time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know who's "responsible" for that Alt+d behavior: I don't know if it's the terminal or if it's the shell (Bash in my case).

It's `bash`, specifically the default command-line editing setup.  [Here](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/features_7.html) is a nice page on what commands can be bound, and how to change the default bindings.

The default binding for `Alt-d` is `kill-word` which is supposed to work like the command of the same name in Emacs.  As you've observed, though, it doesn't—Emacs would consider the space between `>>` and the tilde in your example to be a word break.  That `bash` does not, I would consider a bug.  Short of getting the source for `bash`, changing it, and recompiling it, I don't know what you can do.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. I'd report it to the Bash team.